# Why I am retrieving more frames being read than they are in folder pyzmq

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, zeromq, pyzmq

I have the following code which is sending video frames being read from folder and sending to server. In total there are 511 frames in a folder, but my code provides more frames in output 1000 frames being read from the folder.

```
SERVER_A_ADDRESS = "tcp://localhost:5555"
CLIENT_ADDRESS = "tcp://*:5553"
SERVER_A_TITLE = "Server A"
SERVER_B_TITLE = "Server B"

context = zmq.Context()
socket_server_a = context.socket(zmq.PUSH)
socket_server_endpoint = context.socket(zmq.PULL)
socket_server_a.connect(SERVER_A_ADDRESS)

socket_server_endpoint.bind(CLIENT_ADDRESS)
destination = {
 "currentSocket": socket_server_a,
 "currentServersTitle": SERVER_A_TITLE,
 "currentEndpoint": SERVER_B_TITLE, }
running = True
endpoint_responses = 0
frame_count = 0
def send_frame(frame, frame_count):
 global destination, running
 try:
    frame = cv2.resize(frame, (224, 224))
    encoded, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
    jpg_as_text = base64.b64encode(buffer)
    destination["currentSocket"].send(jpg_as_text)
    print(f"{strftime('%H:%M:%S')} ( + ) :  {destination['currentServersTitle']} received frame {frame_count}")
 except Exception as Error:
    print(
        f"{strftime('%H:%M:%S')} ( ! ) :  Error frame {frame_count}\n\n> KILLING CONNECTIONS\n\nERROR MESSAGE: {Error}")
    running = False
def main():
 global destination, running, frame_count
 filenames = [img for img in glob.glob("video-frames/*.jpg")]
 fps = 5
 interval = int(1 / fps)
 while running:
    filenames = sorted(filenames, key=os.path.getctime) or filenames.sort(key=os.path.getctime)
    for img in filenames:
        frame = cv2.imread(img)
        frame_count += 1
        threading.Thread(target=send_frame, args=(frame, frame_count)).start()
        time.sleep(interval)
 destination["currentSocket"].close()
if  __name__ == "__main__":
 main()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Q** : *"Why I am retrieving more frames being read than they are in folder"*

The code is very seldom to do anything else, than that it was typed in.

**Machines do not think**, they indeed obey **our** instructions, one step after another :

```
#     +++++++-------------------------------------------------- weak control-VAR
#     |||||||
#     vvvvvvv
while running: # _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ INFINITE LOOP
    filenames = sorted( filenames,      key = os.path.getctime )\
                or      filenames.sort( key = os.path.getctime )# .SET | .UPD
    ###################################### .ITERATE over []-members
    for img in filenames: # .............# .GET img
        frame = cv2.imread( img )        # .SET frame
        ...                              # .??? whatever
        #................................# .??? goes here on
    ###################################### .ITERATE.NEXT()
# _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ REPEAT INFINITE LOOP
```

in "nominal" conditions, this will run again and again and again and again, as was coded.

Having nothing but a "soft" break to exit this infinite loop, on a first `Exception`, be it the handled one or any other, the problem is in no explicit termination being present to stop, after your wish not to process *"more frames ... than they are in folder"*. This condition is ignored by the code as-is, so the part ***WHY*** is clear.

---

Solution?

Refactor the code, so as to match your actual wish, hard-stopping or soft-stopping the infinite loop once the `filenames`-list was processed once and only once. If the folder content is dynamic (changing in time), more efforts are needed to re-factor the code, so start from what you need and want to do, not from what the as-is code (only) obeys to do (as was instructed there to do).